# I want to use auto complete/ typeahead feature in ionic app

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have tried using UI bootstrap and ion-autocomplete - they work best with static data. But I am not able to get it to work with a $http request. The data is returning but when I bind the result to a scope object it's not getting populated.

The below code snippet is for Ui bootstrap

```js
$scope.autocomplete = function(query){

  searchAutocompleteService.autoComplete(query).
   then(
     function(result){
      $scope.Categories = result.data;
     },
     function(error){
      
     }
    )

 }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText" ng-keydown="autocomplete(searchText)" uib-typeahead="state for state in Categories" typeahead-no-results="noResults">
```

The below snippet is for ion-autocomplete

```js
$scope.callbackMethod = function (query, isInitializing) {
    searchAutocompleteService.autoComplete(query).
   then(
     function(result){
      return result.data;
     },
     function(error){
                      return result.error;
     }
    )
}
```

```html
<input ion-autocomplete type="text" ng-model="searchText" readonly="readonly" 
       class="ion-autocomplete" autocomplete="off" items-method="callbackMethod(query)"  
       items-method-value-key="items" item-value-key="name"
       item-view-value-key="names" max-selected-items="1" />
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please add current code and more details to help other members answer your question.

Comment: I have attached the code snippet that I tried to use for bootstrap UI and ion-autocomplete